# htaccess redirect URL with sub directories to php file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a Specific root URL (in this example "test") with unknown sub directories to a php file.

example URL

```
http://domain.com/test
http://domain.com/test/sub1
http://domain.com/test/sub1/sub2
```

I have tried with this .htacces code

```
RewriteRule ^test(/.*)?$ redirect.php?path=$1
```

"Edit"

I use this code to split the $path

```
$path = explode("/", $_GET['path']);
```

But when I run print_r on $path in my redirect.php file array 0 is empty

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => sub1 [2] => sub2 )
```

How can I get the full path in my array?

Comment: You'd have to show you build `$path`. PHP will NOT turn a get query value into an array unless the value's key had `[]` in the name, and even then wouldn't split by directory separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture full path then use `RewriteCond` with `REQUEST_URI` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(test(?:/.*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ redirect.php?path=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a GET variable in PHP, you should use something like this:

`$path = $_GET['path'];
echo $path;`

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I use this to split the $path. $path = explode("/", $_GET['path']); and then I use print_r to see the result. But array 0 is empty.